# Using do_shortcode with another shortcode as attributes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to place a shortcode in a template, using `do_shortcode`. The shortcode I am trying to execute is this:

```
[image_with_animation image_url="3185" animation="Fade In" img_link_target="_self"]
```

My challenge is that the attribute "3185" would need to come from another shortcode, which is:

```
[field ImgPortFull]
```

I've tried the obvious way:

```
echo do_shortcode ( '[image_with_animation image_url="'.[field ImgPortFull].'" animation="Fade In" img_link_target="_self"]' );
```

and various other ways, but I can't get it to work.
Does anybody have a solution?

BTW, if anyone was wondering, I am using a combination of the plugins "Visual Composer" and "Custom Content".

Comment: To be really honest here, firstly, you are doing something terribly wrong here. There is one big flaw in your planning here. Secondly, what you are trying to do is slow, as shortcodes needs to be parsed by the shortcode handler. Thirdly, doing `do_shortcode` is almost always a sign of bad planning

Comment: Reading the last part of your question, I would simply extract what I need from both plugins, merge what I need and create something simpler and more effecient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call do_shortcode on each shortcode.  So try:

```
echo do_shortcode ( '[image_with_animation image_url="'.do_shortcode ('[field ImgPortFull]').'" animation="Fade In" img_link_target="_self"]' );
```